# Call Mapbox GL Function from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I have a [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com) map on a page, which loads into a sliding panel which is controlled by jQuery.

If I change the browser window size and toggle the panel, the map often appears only partially filling its container. This is a known issue with the Mapbox GL API.

From their documentation:

> If you’re hiding your map initially with something like display:none
>   and showing it dynamically with JavaScript, it may have some problems
>   appearing and sizing correctly. The map can’t figure out its own size
>   when it’s hidden from the page, since it doesn’t have a size in the
>   browser’s calculation.
>
> With Mapbox GL JS you can call map.resize() to detect and resize the
>   map

So, I need to call Mapbox's map.resize() function from within my jQuery code, when the sliding panel is opened.  Trouble is, I can't seem to get it to work.  I've tried the following:

```
1: $(map).trigger('resize');
2: $(window.map).resize();
3: $(window.map).trigger('resize');
as well as
4: $(window).trigger('resize');
```

Thing is, I'm not sure about my syntax here and the correct way to call a function residing in another script from within jQuery.  I've confirmed that the 'map' object is global, as typing `map.resize()` directly into my browser's dev tools console works [ie. fixes the map display]. I just can't seem to get jQuery to pass the function.

Also strange is that `$(window).trigger('resize')` didn't work, as manually resizing the browser window automatically triggers the 'map.resize()' function too [and fixes the map rendering].

EDIT:

Should have mentioned. I've made the `map` object available globally with: `window.map = map;` inside the mapbox.js script and made sure that the mapbox.js script loads before the jQuery one, but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this in the end.  The problem was that the code I was using to trigger the map redraw was as follows:

```
//inside jQuery map click function
$("#map").slideToggle(200);
$(window.map).resize();
```

Being a bit of a jQuery newbie, I [idiotically] assumed that those commands would fire sequentially but, of course, the `slideToggle()` animation is asynchronous. Therefore jQuery was calling the Mapbox `resize()` function before the sliding panel had reached its final dimensions. Thus causing the map to default to its fallback size of 400x300px

All I needed to do was stick the call to Mapbox `resize()` into an anonymous function, triggered after the `slidetoggle()` has completed:

```
$("#map").slideToggle(200, function() 
{
        $(window.map).resize();
});
```

There is still a slight visual glitch in that the map will initially appear at 400x300px, before quickly snapping to fill its container. But since this was a bit of an edge case, dependent on the user having resized their browser window in between toggling the map open and closed, it's good enough for me to deem it solved.